# Insertar un texto utilizando REALLOC

Tags: c, manejo-de-memoria

La consigna es la siguiente (ignoro el hacerlo en una función):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que desarrollé es el siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int i = 0, j;
    char ingreso;

    /*Initial memory allocation*/
    char *ptr = malloc(sizeof(char) + 1);

    do
    {
        ingreso = getche();

        /*Reallocationg memory*/
        if (i > 0  &&  ingreso != '\r')
        {
            ptr = (char *)realloc(ptr, sizeof(char)*i + 1);
        }
        ptr[i] = ingreso;
        i++;
    }
    while (ingreso != '\r');

    ptr[i+1] = '\0';

    printf("\nLos datos ingresados fueron:\n\n");
    for (j=0; j<=i; j++)
    {
        printf("%c ", ptr[j]);
    }

}
```

Cuando lo ejecuto, el primer y segundo input no se guarda correctamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy casi seguro que el problema radica en el momento de manejar la memoria dinámica, dudo demasiado que sea un problema relacionado con la impresión de los datos ingresados.

Por una parte no entiendo por qué esto sucede, y por otra parte quería preguntarles que sugerencia me darían, como ustedes resolverían este problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Estoy casi seguro que el problema radica en el momento de manejar la memoria dinámica, dudo demasiado que sea un problema relacionado con la impresión de los datos ingresados.

Creo que te vas a reir.

Cambia tu codigo a:

```
printf("\nLos datos ingresados fueron:\n\n");
for (j=0; j<i-1; j++)
{
    printf("%c ", ptr[j]);
}
```

Estas accediendo a mas datos de los que tocan. Uno de los caracteres lo que hace al colocarse en la terminal es regresar al principio de la fila. Y el ultimo al que accedias es la figura rara que sale.

Comment: La verdad que sí, me reí mucho jaja. Hace varios meses que no toco C, y son minusidades que uno se va olvidando. Muchas gracias.